# Wordpress media has all disappeared on wp-admin but still on the server

Tags: uploads, media

I realise this is a very common problem and I have done all the basic debugging - deactivating plugins, changing to 2020, permalinks and various fixes have been suggested. None have worked so far. Seems to have happened with the latest wp update. I tried going to a backup but that hasn't fixed it so I am a bit stumped.

Does anyone have any suggestions, literally all my files have gone from the upload. but they still appear on the site.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Can you explain further what you mean by they're all gone? The media library is empty? The media library only shows broken images? Do you mean the media library page or do you mean the modal dialog? Or both? It's not clear what your problem is, it could be several things, help us narrow it down by giving us more details, especially information about when it happened, e.g. did you migrate your site? A plugin update? When you say they are gone from the upload, do you mean the files are physically gone in the `wp-content/uploads` folder?

Comment: Sorry to clarify wp-content/uploads has all my files in it. The library is not showing any of them literally it is empty so I was thinking the paths might have been messed up by the latest wordpress but I have tried all simple fixes and all the advice I can find on  google. at a loss.

Comment: also to clarify this happened during a period while no changes made by me but wp updated. My uploads are by year if that helps too. many thanks